# Micro HDMI to VGA and VGA to HDMI adapter

Tags: boot, hardware, linux, hdmi, raspbian-buster

i have VGA cable i try to connect raspberry pi 4 with Micro HDMI to VGA and VGA to HDMI. display doesn't showing anything. what setting should i use.
[image]

Comment: Surely that would depend upon which resolutions your adaptors support.

Comment: the two adapters may be uni-directional ... input on left, output on right for both in the picture

Comment: That is never going to work. VGA doesn't carry the same signal as HDMI. You need an active adapter to convert HDMI to VGA, it won't ever work in reverse like you're asking.

Comment: You would be better off with a micro-HMDI-to-HDMI-adapter and a standard HDMI cable.

Answer (score 0):

That is never going to work. VGA doesn't carry the same signal as HDMI. You need an active adapter to convert HDMI to VGA, it won't ever work in reverse like you're asking. – [Dougie Aug 15 at 0:12](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/130678/micro-hdmi-to-vga-and-vga-to-hdmi-adapter#comment223701_130678)

You would be better off with a micro-HMDI-to-HDMI-adapter and a standard HDMI cable. – [Pete Hooper Aug 15 at 15:44](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/130678/micro-hdmi-to-vga-and-vga-to-hdmi-adapter#comment223717_130678)